# Check if two dates completely overlaps a date range

Tags: sql, .net, linq, datetime

I have a parking permit table with validFrom and validTo fields which are datetime fields.  I also have another table called OvernightParkingSetting which has two datetime fields NightStart and NightEnd.

What I need is to read all of the parking permits that are valid beginning before NightStart and ending after NightEnd, meaning it is a pass valid for overnight parking.

I'm trying to do this in .NET, LINQ

Any help with the logic or the design would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does that have to do with the validfrom and validto fields? And what do you mean by completely cross NightStart and NightEnd?

Comment: Check this SO question [This SO Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap/325964#325964

Comment: you can cast it to `DateTime` and use build-in comparer.

Comment: How many rows in OvernightParkingSetting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to write the whole code for your project, but I can help you in the right direction with the logic and SQL statement. You'll need to use a couple subqueries to get the values from the OvernightParkingSetting table that you need.

Start here:

```
SELECT * FROM parkingPermitTable
WHERE validFrom < SELECT(NightStart FROM OvernightParkingSetting) 
    AND validTo > SELECT(NightEnd FROM OvernightParkingSetting)
```

Here I'm making the assumption that your OvernightParkingSetting table has only one row. If it does not, you need to find a way to restrict that to receiving a specific night start and night end time.

This will select any rows from the parking permit table that has a valid from time earlier than the night start time, as well as a valid to time that is later than the night end time. If you want this to be inclusive, you can change the less than and greater than operators accordingly.

**EDIT**

This also makes the assumptions that all of the variables are datetime variables. I believe that is the variable that would be most relevant here.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem? Just curious what your solution was.